# How to get selected option in change callback of AngularDart component

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I want to use a select HTML element to filter items in a table. For that I have a model value `selectedCategoryId` and event callback  `onFilterCategory` for the change event. But when callback gets called the value `selectedCategoryId` is `null`.

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<select id="category"
        class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedCategoryId"
        (change)="onFilterCategory()">
    <option *ngFor="let category of categories"
            value="{{category.id}}">
        {{category.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

And the following dart snippet:

```
void onFilterCategory() {
    print('onFilterCategory');
    print('this.selectedCategoryId: ' + this.selectedCategoryId);
}
```

Do I need to use another callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngModelChange` is the event and `$event` the value

```
(ngModelChange)="onFilterCategory($event)"
```

with

```
 void onFilterCategory(String value) {
```

Because you have 2-way binding

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedCategoryId"
```

you can also use

```
(ngModelChange)="onFilterCategory()"
```

with the `onFilterCategory()` as it is in your question.

The `change` event doesn't work because it fires too early - before `[(ngModel)]="selectedCategoryId"` was able to update `selectedCategoryId`.

Comment: When I use `[(ngModel)]` in combination with `(ngModelChange)` I get a compiler warning: `ParseErrorLevel.FATAL: Found multiple events with the same name: ngModelChange. You should merge the handlers into a single statement. [(ngModel)]="selectedCategoryId"`

Comment: What's the compiler warning?

Comment: These are my dependencies: `angular: ^5.0.0-alpha`
and `angular_forms: ^2.0.0-alpha`

Comment: This is the warning: `ParseErrorLevel.FATAL: Found multiple events with the same name: ngModelChange. You should merge the handlers into a single statement. [(ngModel)]="selectedCategoryId"`

Comment: I see. That's new. Then change `[(ngModel)]="selectedCategoryId"` to `[ngModel]="selectedCategoryId"`and use `(ngModelChange)="onFilterCategory($event)"`